# Load Google Maps markers via ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-maps, symfony, google-maps-api-3

I want to load the markers for a Google Map via ajax with my own geolocation service. The ajax functionality comes from jQuery. My code to load the markers is the following:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(49.47143, 11.107489999999984);
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 8,
            center: myLatlng
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('googlemap'), mapOptions);

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "{{ path('jobs_ajax_get_geolocation') }}",
            data: "addr="+encodeURI("{{ company.getAddress }}, {{ company.getZipCode }} {{ company.getCity }}"),
            success: function(data) {
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.long),
                    map: map,
                    title: 'test'
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

The map loads with the correct initialize-location, but no marker is shown. There are ajax results provided by the url ({{ path('jobs_ajax_get_geolocation') }}; it's a symfony-route).

Where is my mistake? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is in the wrong scope.

You declared `var marker` inside function definition. Outside of the function it will not exist. But you need it in the outer scope.

Try declare it before closure:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(49.47143, 11.107489999999984);
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 8,
            center: myLatlng
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('googlemap'), mapOptions);
        var marker;

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "{{ path('jobs_ajax_get_geolocation') }}",
            data: "addr="+encodeURI("{{ company.getAddress }}, {{ company.getZipCode }} {{ company.getCity }}"),
            success: function(data) {
                    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.long),
                    map: map,
                    title: 'test'
                });
            }
        });
    });
```